# Swift Playgrounds Class Viewcontroller has no member ""?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller, swift-playground

I am relatively new to swift programming and came across this problem, I honestly have no idea how to fix this. I have a viewcontroller in playgrounds and have a button on that view. I have a class called CanvasView, which has the following code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

public class CanvasView: UIView {

var lineColor: UIColor!
var lineWidth: CGFloat!

var path: UIBezierPath!
var touchPoint: CGPoint!
var startPoint: CGPoint!

public override func layoutSubviews() {
    setupDefaultSettings()
}

// control touches
public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        startPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: startPoint)
    }
}

public override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        touchPoint = touch.location(in: self)
    }

    path.addLine(to: touchPoint)
    startPoint = touchPoint

    drawShapeLayer()
}

// Function to clear the drawn path
func clearCanvas() {
    guard let path = path else { return }
    path.removeAllPoints()
    layer.sublayers = nil
    setNeedsDisplay()
}

// draw shape on layer
public func drawShapeLayer() {
    guard let path = path else { return }
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = lineColor.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    setNeedsDisplay()
}

public func setupDefaultSettings() {
    lineColor = .black
    lineWidth = 5

    clipsToBounds = true
    isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
 }

}
```

As you can see that class has a method called clearCanvas() which clears the canvas. In my view controller I made an object that inherits from the CanvasView class and tried to call the clearCanvas function using a button but that gives me the error that the class GameViewController has no member drawView? Even though it shows it does like 10 lines above. Code for GameViewController:

```
import Foundation
import CoreML
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

public class GameViewController : UIViewController {

public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //MARK: Variables and constants
    let yellowColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.92, blue:0.23, alpha:1.0)
    var roundNumber = 1
    var currentScore = 0

    //MARK: Setting up the UI
    //Setting up the initial view
    let view = UIView()
    self.view = view
    view.backgroundColor = yellowColor

    //Adding the view which can be drawn on
    let drawView = CanvasView()
    drawView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    drawView.frame = CGRect(x: 12.5, y: 250, width: 350, height: 350)
    drawView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    view.addSubview(drawView)

    //Adding a button to start the round
    let startRoundButton = UIButton()
    startRoundButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 100, height: 50)
    view.addSubview(startRoundButton)

    startRoundButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startRoundButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

    //Adding a button clear the canvas
    let clearCanvasButton = UIButton()
    let clearCanvasButtonImage = UIImage(named: "clearButton")
    clearCanvasButton.setImage(clearCanvasButtonImage, for: .normal)
    clearCanvasButton.frame = CGRect(x: 12.5, y: 620, width: 110, height: 27)
    view.addSubview(clearCanvasButton)

    clearCanvasButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clearCanvasButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

    //MARK: Functions
    func clearDrawView() {
        drawView.clearCanvas()
    }

}

@objc func startRoundButtonPressed() {

}

@objc func clearCanvasButtonPressed() {
    GameViewController.clearDrawView()
 }

}
```

I did copy the class CanvasView so maybe there is something thats screwing up the calling of the method in there. I would be very grateful if someone could help me solve this (maybe very stupid) problem, and keep in mind this was made in playgrounds on mac and not in xcode. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `clearDrawView()` is indeed not a member but a nested function in `viewDidLoad()`.

Moving the definition to the class level should help. However, you also have to define `drawView` as a member (i.e. at class level) to make it visible to `clearDrawView()`:

```
public class GameViewController : UIViewController {

    let drawView = CanvasView() // <--- move it here from viewDidLoad()

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // do the necessary stuff, including drawView setup
    }

    func clearDrawView() {
        drawView.clearCanvas()
    }

    @objc func clearCanvasButtonPressed() {
        clearDrawView() // note: not "GameViewController.clearDrawView()" because it's an instance method
    }
}
```

For better understanding check [Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) and [Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID234) in Apple docs.

Comment: Thanks soooo much dude! Can't believe I hadn't tried that yet!